# Using adhesive to attach Durock to subfloor?

Tags: tile, adhesive, mortar, cement-board

[Durock's official installation guide](https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/canada/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/cgc-durock-cement-board-how-to-guide-en-can-DNG_RIG003E.pdf) says that using adhesive with a 5/8" v-notched trowel is a possible means of laminating the board to the subfloor:

[image]

However I'm not certain which adhesive to use. It also seems like this would get expensive quick with some of the stuff I'm seeing available (maybe that is why mortar is more typical).

If I were to go the adhesive route, what adhesive should I use? And has anyone had good/bad experiences with adhesive vs mortar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding has always been that thinset mortar (the same stuff you'd use on top of it for tile) is preferred.

Presumably a construction adhesive (preferably in the large tubes, not the 10 oz tiny ones) that is compatible with cementboard and the subfloor would also work, since they specify that. I suppose they might mean "mastic" (by the several-gallon pail) except - they don't say that.

Probably worth an email or phone call if you don't intend to use thinset mortar to disambiguate.